# Convert Json String to Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I have below Json string which needs to be converted to Datatable C#

```
[ { "Genre": "Fiction", "Author": "J K Rowling", "Books": [ { "Name": "Philospher's Stone", "Published": "1997" }, { "Name": "Chamber of Secrets", "Published": "1998" }, { "Name": "Prisoner of Azkaban", "Published": "1999" }, { "Name": "Goblet of Fire", "Published": "2000" }, { "Name": "Order of Phoenix", "Published": "2003" } ] }, { "Genre": "Non Fiction", "Author": "George Orwell", "Books": [ { "Name": "Animal Farm", "Published": "1952" }, { "Name": "Nineteen Eighty Four", "Published": "1949" } ] } ]
```

Datatable :

| Genre | Author | Books | Published |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fiction | JK ROWLING | Philospher's Stone | 1997 |
| Fiction | JK ROWLING | Chamber of Secrets | 1998 |
| Fiction | JK ROWLING | Prisoner of Azkaban | 1999 |
| Fiction | JK ROWLING | Goblet of Fire | 2000 |
| Fiction | JK ROWLING | Order of Phoenix | 2003 |
| Non Fiction | George Orwell | Animal Farm | 1952 |
| Non Fiction | George Orwell | Nineteen Eighty Four | 1949 |

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried, and what's currently blocking you?

Comment: DataSet data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);

Comment: Please, don't use datatables in your code, IDE can't help you with access to DT fields.  Classes will save much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your json object to some class.

```
List<Books> UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Books>>(jsonString);
```

and then populate the datatable form this list like this.

```
private static DataTable ConvertToDatatable<T>(List<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]); 
        else
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    object[] values = new object[props.Count];
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return table;
 }
```

Comment: Sadly this Solution will not work because it is a list of books with some general metadata surrond with

Comment: it depends on how you make your class. You can Make a class of Meta data and the third element of that object can be a list of another object named Books. the sub class can have data members Name and published.

Comment: `public class  metadata{ string Genre; string Author; List<Books> books; }` then Books can be `public class Books{string Name; string Published}`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to you on stackoverflow.
For such questions I always use pages like
https://json2csharp.com/
to convert the json to csharp objects. You can copy it and give it meaningful names after that.

But then you can deserialize your json - string directly with JsonConvert and you can use it. I like to use DomainObjects to save it with EntityFramework in the database.

```
public class DomainObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Published { get; set; } 
    public string Genre { get; set; } 
    public string Author { get; set; } 
}


[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>( jsonString );

    DomainObject[] values = root.Books.Select( x => new DomainObject()
            { Author = root.Author, Genre = root.Genre, Name = x.Name, Published = x.Published } )
           .ToArray();

}
```